# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string - provider doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

i have problem somewhere in Router and this is error message React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string.

I wrote every articles about this problem, but i still didn't resolve it.

I am a beginner in React and i want start with new project.

my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'redux';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import App from './js/pages/App/App';
import Container from './js/components/Container/Container';

import store from './js/store';

const app = document.getElementById('app');
const newHistory = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={newHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <Route path="/container" component={Container} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
),
app
);

module.hot.accept();
```

my store.js

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from "redux";

import {createLogger} from "redux-logger";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware";
import {save, load} from "redux-localstorage-simple";


import reducer from "./reducers/index";

var createStoreWithMiddleware = null;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
createStoreWithMiddleware
    = applyMiddleware(
    promise(),
    thunk,
    createLogger()
)(createStore);
}
else {
createStoreWithMiddleware
    = applyMiddleware(
    promise(),
    thunk
)(createStore);
}

//const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, createLogger());

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(
reducer // Loading done here
);
export default store;
```

i think that somewhere here is problem, because when i delete Provider i see App page.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` do you use? You can see it listed in `package.json` under `dependencies` or `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Provider** is a higher-order component provided by React Redux that lets you bind Redux to React.

As per the documentation of redux: 
https://redux.js.org/advanced/usagewithreactrouter

You need to

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
```

Comment: Thanks, thats helped :)